# Codrops Thumbnail Grid preview on top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am playing with [Codrops' Thumbnail Grid example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/), but I wonder if anyone can help me understand **how can I make the expandable preview appear on the top of the selected image and not bellow?**

Comment: On the top of what? You may need to be more clear with your question

Comment: I think you mean above, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried prepending the div, as it is set to append, but prepending it I continue to have the height issue, if you test the source files you will understand

Answer (score -1):

Modify this line in Codrops to use prepend instead of append

```
// append preview element to the item
this.$item.prepend( this.getEl() );
```

The line is inside this function

*Preview.prototype = { create : function() {*

**Demo (without any styles!):**

http://jsbin.com/UhaFube/1/

Comment: As I stated on the comments of the question, I have tried prepending the displaying element, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see the *working* sample link.. do you get any errors?